# SSRS Set Date/Time parameter to NULL based on previous paremeter's selection

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 3 parameters in an SSRS report: rptFiscalyearId, rptStartDate, rptEndDate.
rptFiscalyearId is a predefined select list of fiscal years.
rptStartDate and rptEndDate are both of type "Date/Time" (i.e., datepickers) and both have "Allow null value" set to true in parameter properties.

The default value of rptFiscalyearId is 0 (meaning "All").

What I'm trying to do is make it so that if the user picks a different value for rptFiscalyearId, then the values for rptStartDate and rptEndDate will both be set to Null.

The only way I'm able to do this is to set the "Available Values" properties in rptStartDate and rptEndDate to an expression like "=IIf(Parameters!rptFiscalyearId.Value > 0, Nothing, Datetime.Now)". However, the problem with this is that by doing so, the parameter is changed to a select list instead of a calendar datepicker.

Is there any way of achieving what I'm looking for without converting my datepicker parameters to select lists?
Is there perhaps some way to do this programatically in the report viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can retain the date picker while setting the available values, but have you considered setting the *default* rptStartDate and rptEndDate values instead? That way, the users would still be to set the values via the date picker - although they would also be able to override the fiscal year start and end dates.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Unfortunately the values do not get updated when the value of rptFiscalyearId is updated. The default value property only seems to apply when the report is first loaded.